# Get the absolute value of a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the absolute value of a number in JavaScript. That is, drop the sign.
I know mathematically I can do this by squaring the number then taking the square root, but I also know that this is horribly inefficient.

```js
x = -25
x = x * x 
x = Math.sqrt(x)
console.log(x)
```

Is there a way in JavaScript to simply drop the sign of a number that is more efficient than the mathematical approach?

Comment: `Math.abs(-25); // 25`

Comment: Nobody yet suggested regular expression? ;-) Or `jQuery.abs()`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You mean like getting the [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a number? The [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) javascript function is designed exactly for this purpose.

```js
var x = -25;
x = Math.abs(x); // x would now be 25 
console.log(x);
```

Here are some test cases from the documentation:

```
Math.abs('-1');     // 1
Math.abs(-2);       // 2
Math.abs(null);     // 0
Math.abs("string"); // NaN
Math.abs();         // NaN
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is a fast way to obtain the absolute value of a number. It's applicable on every language:

```js
x = -25;
console.log((x ^ (x >> 31)) - (x >> 31));
```

Comment: Does this assume a 32 bit number?

Comment: Doesn't JavaScript use 64bit (double) numbers?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I believe that binary operators implicitly typecast JS numbers to 32 bit signed integers during the operations. Example: `(Math.pow(2,32)-1)|0 === -1` as opposed to `4294967295`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Just read the ECMA spec, and apparently some operators convert numbers to signed 32 bit integers, while some others operators convert numbers to unsigned 32 bit integers.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to see how JavaScript implements this feature under the hood you can check out this post.

## [Blog Post](https://codewithintent.com/how-to-read-native-javascript-code)

Here is the implementation based on the chromium source code.

```js
function MathAbs(x) {
  x = +x;
  return (x > 0) ? x : 0 - x;
}

console.log(MathAbs(-25));
```

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo  - I think it answers it quite well, although definitely a bit terse. It's suggesting you could use `absx=Math.abs(x);` or you could create a function (`MathAbs`) or even directly use `absx=(x > 0) ? x : 0 - x;`. Perhaps adding a similar statement to the answer would help.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for `Math.abs(x)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution

```
Math.max(x,-x)
```

```js
let abs = x => Math.max(x,-x);

console.log( abs(24), abs(-24) );
```

Also the [Rick answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37532841/860099) can be shorted to `x>0 ? x : -x`

Answer (score 0):

> to simply drop the sign of a number

```js
var x = -25;
+`${x}`.replace('-', '');
```